# C# MVC 5 - \\ Executar query com resultado de outra query

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvc

Pessoal estou vindo do `PHP` e aprendendo `C#` `MVC` enquanto migro as aplicações que tenho.
Me deparei com o seguinte problema que não consigo achar uma solução:

Essa é minha classe  que gera o menu dinamicamente no sistema:

```
public class WebEstMenuAplicacao
{
    private ConexaoOracle bd;

    public List<WebEstMenu> MenuSistema(int gru_in_codigo)
    {
        using (bd = new ConexaoOracle())
        {
            var strQuery = "select " +
                             " t.men_in_codigo, " +
                             " t.men_st_descricao," +
                             " t.men_st_caminho," +
                             " t.men_st_icone," +
                             " t.men_st_status" +
                           " from " +
                             " MGESTOQUE.WEB_EST_SYSMENU t ";
            //strQuery += string.Format(" t.gru_in_codigo= ('{0}')", gru_in_codigo);
            var retorno = bd.ExecutaComandoComRetorno(strQuery);
            return ReaderEmListaMenu(retorno);
        }
    }

    public List<WebEstMenu> ReaderEmListaMenu(OracleDataReader reader)
    {
        var tabAplicacao = new List<WebEstMenu>();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            var tempoObjeto = new WebEstMenu()
            {
                men_in_codigo = int.Parse(reader["men_in_codigo"].ToString()),
                men_st_descricao = reader["men_st_descricao"].ToString(),
                men_st_caminho = reader["men_st_caminho"].ToString(),
                men_st_icone = reader["men_st_icone"].ToString(),
                men_st_status = int.Parse(reader["men_st_status"].ToString())
            };
            tabAplicacao.Add(tempoObjeto);
        }
        reader.Close();
        return tabAplicacao;
    }
}
```

Esse é meu controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    if (tempData.vORG_IN_CODIGO > 0)
    {
        var appWebEstMenu = new WebEstMenuAplicacao();
        var webEstMenu = appWebEstMenu.MenuSistema(tempData.vGRU_IN_CODIGO);

        if (webEstMenu == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        return View(webEstMenu);

    } 
    else
    {
        TempData["msg"] = "<script>jAlert('Sua sessão expirou favor logar novamente.','Erro');</script>";
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Login");
    }
}
```

Esse código gera o menu no meu sistema verificando o nível de acesso do colaborador. Até esse momento eu consegui normalmente, mas não estou conseguindo implementar a verificação do submenu. Onde ele deve percorrer o LIST do MENU e pesquisar os itens de submenu. E depois retornar os dois models para minha view.

Tabela de SubMenu

```
select t.sub_in_codigo,
       t.men_in_codigo,
       t.sub_st_descricao,
       t.sub_st_icone,
       t.sub_in_status,
       t.sub_st_url
from 
 MGESTOQUE.WEB_EST_SYSSUBMENU t
```

Answer (score 0):

Seu objeto **tabAplicacao** é a lista que contém os seus Menus. Dessa forma, se você precisa percorrê-la, você pode fazer dessa forma:

Ex.:

```
var tabAplicacao = new List<WebEstMenu>();
var subMenusList = new List<SubMenu>();

foreach(WebEstMenu menu in tabAplicacao)
{
     // 1. Select na tabela de sub-menus, utilizando o código do menu em questão.
     menu.men_in_codigo
     // 2. Captura os sub-menus retornados pela busca.
     // 3. Adiciona-os em uma nova lista de sub-menus. (Este objeto deve ser passado para a sua View).
}
```

Comment: Italo obrigado pela resposta, consegui ter uma ideia e resolver meu problema.

Answer (score 0):

Depois de quebrar a cabeça, consegui achar uma solução:

Criei uma nova classe herdando a classe MENU:

Classe MENU

```
    namespace Estoque.Dominio
{
    public class WebEstMenu
    {
        public int men_in_codigo { get; set; }
        public string men_st_descricao { get; set; }
        public string men_st_caminho { get; set; }        
        public string men_st_icone { get; set; }
        public int men_st_status { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Classe SubMenu

```
    namespace Estoque.Dominio
{
    public class WebEstSubMenu : WebEstMenu
    {
        public int Sub_in_codigo { get; set; }
        public string Sub_st_descricao { get; set; }
        public string Sub_st_icone { get; set; }
        public string Sub_st_url { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Criei a classe de aplicação onde executa as querys do MENU e SUBMENU, populando minhas classes de domínio.

[image: Populando classes de dominio]

```
   public class WebEstAplicacao
    {
        private ConexaoOracle bd;


       public List<WebEstSubMenu> MenuSistema(int gru_in_codigo)
               {
                   using (bd = new ConexaoOracle())
                   {
                       var strQuery = "select " +
                                        " t.men_in_codigo, " +
                                        " t.men_st_descricao," +
                                        " t.men_st_caminho," +
                                        " t.men_st_icone," +
                                        " t.men_st_status" +
                                      " from " +
                                        " MGESTOQUE.WEB_EST_SYSMENU t ";
                       //strQuery += string.Format(" t.gru_st_nome = LOWER('{0}')", gru_st_nome);
                       var retorno = bd.ExecutaComandoComRetorno(strQuery);
                       return ReaderEmListaMenu(retorno);
                   }
               }

               //
               public List<WebEstSubMenu> ReaderEmListaMenu(OracleDataReader reader)
               {
                   var tabAplicacaoMenu = new List<WebEstSubMenu>();
                   var appWebSubMenu = new WebEstSubMenuAplicacao();

                   while (reader.Read())
                   {
                       var tempoObjeto = new WebEstSubMenu()
                       {
                           men_in_codigo = int.Parse(reader["men_in_codigo"].ToString()),
                           men_st_descricao = reader["men_st_descricao"].ToString(),
                           men_st_caminho = reader["men_st_caminho"].ToString(),
                           men_st_icone = reader["men_st_icone"].ToString(),
                           men_st_status = int.Parse(reader["men_st_status"].ToString())
                       };
                       tabAplicacaoMenu.Add(tempoObjeto);
                        using (bd = new ConexaoOracle())
                        {
                            var strQuery = "select " +
                                          "  t.sub_in_codigo," +
                                          " t.men_in_codigo," +
                                          " t.sub_st_descricao," +
                                          " t.sub_st_icone," +
                                          " t.sub_in_status," +
                                          " t.sub_st_url" +
                                          " from MGESTOQUE.WEB_EST_SYSSUBMENU t";
                            strQuery += " where ";
                            strQuery += string.Format(" t.men_in_codigo = {0}", int.Parse(reader["men_in_codigo"].ToString()));
                            //strQuery += string.Format(" t.gru_st_nome = LOWER('{0}')", gru_st_nome);
                            var retorno = bd.ExecutaComandoComRetorno(strQuery);
                                while (retorno.Read())
                                {
                                    var tempoObjetoSub = new WebEstSubMenu()
                                    {
                                        men_in_codigo = int.Parse(reader["men_in_codigo"].ToString()),
                                        men_st_descricao = reader["men_st_descricao"].ToString(),
                                        men_st_caminho = reader["men_st_caminho"].ToString(),
                                        men_st_icone = reader["men_st_icone"].ToString(),
                                        men_st_status = int.Parse(reader["men_st_status"].ToString()),
                                        Sub_in_codigo = int.Parse(retorno["sub_in_codigo"].ToString()),
                                        Sub_st_descricao = retorno["sub_st_descricao"].ToString(),
                                        Sub_st_icone = retorno["Sub_st_icone"].ToString(),
                                        Sub_st_url = retorno["sub_st_url"].ToString()
                                    };
                                         tabAplicacaoMenu.Add(tempoObjetoSub);
                                }
                        }       
                   }
                   reader.Close();
                   return tabAplicacaoMenu;
               }
    }
```

Dentro do meu _Layout.cshtml, apanhei um pouco no Razor, mas consegui chegar a solução:

```
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                var menu2 = 0;
                var menu = int.Parse(Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Sub_in_codigo).ToString());
                menu2 = int.Parse(Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.men_in_codigo).ToString());

                if (menu == 0)
                {

                    @Html.Raw(" <li class='treeview'>");
                    @Html.Raw("<a href='#'> "+
                                "<i class='fa fa-random'></i>"+
                                "<span>"+ @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.men_st_descricao).ToString() + "</span> "+
                                "<span class='pull-right-container'>"+
                                "<i class='fa fa-angle-left pull-right'></i>"+
                                "</span>"+
                                "</a>");
                    @Html.Raw("<ul class='treeview-menu'>");

                    foreach (var subemnuitem in Model)
                    {
                        var SubMenu = int.Parse(Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => subemnuitem.men_in_codigo).ToString());
                        var menu3 = int.Parse(Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => subemnuitem.Sub_in_codigo).ToString());

                        if (SubMenu == menu2 && menu3 > 0)
                        {
                            @Html.Raw("<li><a href='#' onclick='LoadingPage('Entradas','Index');'><i class='fa fa-sign-in'></i>"+ @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => subemnuitem.Sub_st_descricao).ToString() + "</a></li>");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //@Html.Raw("</ul>");
                           // break;
                        }
                    }
                    @Html.Raw("</ul>");

                }
                else
                {

                    @Html.Raw("</li>");
                }
            }
```

Gerando o menu dinamicamente.

[image: Menu Dinamico]